Unable to load the contents of CSV file(containing date in the filename) from S3 to Snowflake
Unable to load the contents of CSV file(containing date in the filename) from S3 Bucket to Snowflake . The file name is like this : EF_FILENAME_TST20241217T010502.csv. The requirement is to load the file from s3 to snowflake table using today's file.(CURRENT DATE). Same thing for next days file(dynamic file with current date in it)
I am using the below code but I think copy into command doesn't supports || to concatenate date in snowflake:
NEED SOME HELP TO ACHEIVE THIS THROUGH SNOWFLAKE USING LANGUAGE : SQL.
COPY INTO table1 (
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  column4,
  column5,
  column6,
  column7,
  column8,
  column9
)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.$1
      /* column1*/,
      t.$2
      /* column2*/,
      t.$3
      /* column3*/,
      t.$4
      /* column4*/,
      CASE
        WHEN t.$5 = 'Create' THEN 1
        WHEN t.$5 = 'Modify' THEN 2
        WHEN t.$5 = 'Delete' THEN 3
      END
      /* column5*/,
      t.$6
      /* column6*/,
      t.$7
      /* column7*/,
      t.$8
      /* column8*/,
      t.$9
      /* column9*/
    FROM
      @DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.S3_SF_DEV/Test/FILE/DATA AS t
  ) PATTERN = '.*EF_FILENAME_TST' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') || 'T.*[.]csv' FILE_FORMAT = (
    TYPE = CSV COMPRESSION = NONE SKIP_HEADER = 1 FIELD_DELIMITER = '|' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
  );


If you set the pattern variable, it should work fine
SET todays_date = TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
SET file_pattern = '.*EF_FILENAME_TST' || $todays_date || 'T.*[.]csv';

this evaluates to
SELECT $file_pattern;

--.*EF_FILENAME_TST20241218T.*[.]csv

And finally use PATTERN => $file_pattern in your COPY INTO command
I tested with internal stage, and it works for me.
COPY INTO table1 (
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4,
    column5,
    column6,
    column7,
    column8,
    column9
)
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.$1,
        t.$2,
        t.$3,
        t.$4,
        CASE
            WHEN t.$5 = 'Create' THEN 1
            WHEN t.$5 = 'Modify' THEN 2
            WHEN t.$5 = 'Delete' THEN 3
        END AS column5,
        t.$6,
        t.$7,
        t.$8,
        t.$9
    FROM @my_internal_stage (PATTERN => $file_pattern) AS t
)
FILE_FORMAT = (
    TYPE = 'CSV',
    COMPRESSION = 'NONE',
    SKIP_HEADER = 1,
    FIELD_DELIMITER = '|',
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
);

